# Issues running celerybeat as a daemon with django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, celery, celerybeat

So I have it working normally and I've tested that it performs exactly as it should but I can't seem to get it to run as a daemon properly. So for starters, I'm running a django app and using mongodb as a backend and I have all the required modules for that

Currently I can run it successfully using

```
celery worker --beat --app=matter.celeryapp --loglevel=DEBUG
```

Where matter is my project folder and celeryapp is the app (I found naming it just celery like in the tutorial just caused it to not work at all)

So I created the files

```
/etc/init.d/celerybeat 
/etc/default/celerybeat
```

and call it using

```
/etc/init.d/celerybeat start
```

but the main issue seems to be that **my configurations are in my Django settings.py**.

For some reason it never seems to read my settings from there. 
I even have my CELERY_APP = matter.celeryapp but that doesn't seem to work.

I know this is incorrect because it uses the logfile shows it's using the default broker instead of mongo

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to `cd` to the right directory? Regardless... I would recommend to use `supervisord` instead. It's far easier to set up and keep running :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the Django settings to your environment. Add to `/etc/default/celerybeat`:

```
# Project path
CELERYD_CHDIR="/path/to/manage.py/dir/"

# Name of projects setting module relative to project path.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="matter.settings"
```